# Yii2 Advance application show directory listing instead web view

Tags: apache, yii2

I just copy my Yii2 advanced app from windows to linux.

PHP, Apache2, etc already installed successfully.

But when I got to `localhost/myweb` It show directory listing instead of web view.

Here is my `apache2.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb/frontend/web/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is `myweb/.htaccess`

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^administrator(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

How I can show web view, instead of directory listing?

Where I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you changed htaccess settings from /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you may need to modify the httpd.conf file located at:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

you should change the following lines from:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and then restart the httpd service